# Changing npm proxy in hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am facing some issues with my network proxy, so I am trying hit and trial sort of approach to try different proxies. I need to give the proxy configuration during composer network install command within npmConfig file, now once I have given one proxy, how can I change it, as I cannot use composer network install again for same business network.

Answer (score 0):

The npmrcFile option is available on the `composer network install` command and once the install is done - the npmrcFile is bundled with that install package on the peers.

Because you cannot build a chaincode container due to proxy issues (ie your issues stated), `start` will not be successful and so thus you cannot use `composer network upgrade` with `-o <options>` to upgrade the business network with new npmrcFile changes via 'options'. This is why its best to try it out your proxy configs in a simple Dev Fabric environment - you can blow away the peer each time and install a new Fabric - once it is working (its a one-off task), then you have the correct npmrcFile to install as appropriate etc.

If need be you could use `wget http://npmregistry:4873/` from a test docker container (where you do a test npm install) to see if you can connect via your network proxy - then once you know, your config file should be read when it (re-)tries the docker build.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually the problem the proxy is password protected and password has special characters. I replaced the special character with percent encoding and it worked in my system. But when I give the same in npmRC it's not working. Though I need to delete the installed chaincode in every peer in order to again give install command and try proxy.